# how to invoke dao method crrectly from same dao method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 dao.

```
@EnableTransactionManagement()
@Repository
public class TTTestFirstImpl  implements TTestFirstDao {

    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    ...

    @Autowired
    public TTestSecondDao secondDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void first() {
        entityManager.persist(new TableTest1().setName("first dao persist"));

        try {
              secondDao.second();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And Also second dao  looks like this:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement()
@Repository
public class TTTestSecondImpl implements TTestSecondDao {

    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    ...

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES)
    public void second() {
        entityManager.persist(...);
        throw new RuntimeException(); // to roll back
    }
```

First and Second method persists data in DB.  in First Dao I have injected Second dao.
I invoke `second()` method from `first()` method.

Everything is well, because of second() method have Propagation.REQUIRES all persist data is roll backed  well (which was persisted from first() and from second() method). There is no data in DB. **Very good!**

Now I have created `third()` method in First Dao Implementation which is similar of `second()` mehtod. Only difference is that `third()` method id written in `TTEstFirstImpl` class.

Now my class looks like this:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement()
@Repository
public class TTTestFirstImpl  implements TTestFirstDao {


    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private TTestFirstDao getSpringProxy() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(this.getClass());
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void third() {

        entityManager.persist(...);
        throw new RuntimeException();

    }


    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void first() {
        entityManager.persist(...);

        try {
            //  dao.second();
            getSpringProxy().third();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I invoke `third()` method, which have `Propagation.REQUIRED`, I do not have same result. Only `third()` methods persist is roll backed. But because of I have `Propagation.REQUIRED` , persist data from `first()` **must be roll backed too.**

If I invoke  `third()` without getSpringProxy() it does not roll backs at all. This is not also clear to me.

p.s I have suck I config in DB:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
 ...
```

Comment: Why on earth do you have the code littered with the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation? This is the same as adding `<tx:annotation-driven />` in XML. Remove it for the classes. Never catch and swallow exceptions, also why would you need to call it on the proxy, just call `this.third()`. The proxy is only needed if you have `REQUIRES_NEW` . Also are you sure you want to use `mode="aspectj"`, that means you have load or compile time weaving enabled (and you shouldn't need a proxy). My guess that is wrong also.

Comment: @M. Deinum As I know without mode="aspectj" annotations won't work inside the same class in Spring (annotations of third will be ignored if the method is called from the same class).

Comment: Correct but it doesn't add anything here because there is already a transaction. Next to that you are doing al ookup to get the proxy. So basically you are trying very hard to work around the aspectj mode.

Comment: what disadvantages does AspectJ have?